# A query with ManyToMany fields

Tags: django, many-to-many

I need to have a view with users that havn't got any group. I have tried to make a query with  `.except` but it has failed because of manytomany fields...

My models :

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    courses_list = models.ManyToManyField('Course', blank=True)
    group_list = models.ManyToManyField('Group', blank=True)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(Assignment)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, through=UserProfile.group_list.through, blank=True)

class Assignment (models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)

class Course(models.Model):
    subscribed = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, through= UserProfile.courses_list.through, blank=True)
```

So, I need to select users subscribed to the assignment (`assignment.course.subscribed.all` send all) that haven't got any group (the problem is that I need to take care of groups linked to this assignment only)

I have tried `groupless = detailedassignment.course.subscribed.exclude(username = group_list.filter(assignment=detailedassignment).members.username.all())` but it doesn't work at all (and i think it is normal when I see the code..)

**Edit :**

I have removed relations in a way, now my models are :

```
My models :

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(Assignment)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, blank=True)

class Assignment (models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)

class Course(models.Model):
    subscribed = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, blank=True)
```

I have tried to use :

```
groupless = detailedassignment.course.subscribed.exclude(user__username__in = Group.objects.filter(assignment=detailedassignment).members.objects.values_list('user__username'))
```

But I have `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'members'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting the `user` reference. So if I interpret you properly, you want something like -

```
groupless = detailedassignment.course.subscribed.exclude(user__username__in = group_list.filter(assignment=detailedassignment).members.objects.values_list('user__username'))
```

OR try this -

```
groupless = UserProfile.objects.filter(courses_list__assignment = detailedassignment).exclude(group_list__assignment=detailedassignment)
```

Also as an aside, your model design looks somewhat skewed, with same references running across each other. And there's no need to add backward references (like in model `Course). Django gives you the functionality for backward referencing. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

Comment: Yes, I dislike it too but I had a problem and this was a solution (hugly, i agree). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509077/load-in-a-multiplechoicefield-values-from-a-manytomany-field

Comment: Really thanks ! For informations the **second one** is just **perfect** !

Comment: You don't need `all()` at the end of the second query, because `filter()` and `exclude()` is already used.

Comment: I have edited, I have removed backward references but it doesn't works anymore :/

Answer (score 0):

So, when the backward reference have been removed, I have used a `related_name` in my ManyToManyField and Rahul's answer with a little edit :

```
groupless = User.objects.filter(course_list__assignment=detailedassignment).exclude(group_list__assignment=detailedassignment)
```

If it can be useful.. :D